# AWS Cognito: Test triggers using postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, triggers, amazon-cognito, password-less

I am very new to AWS and I am trying to implement passwordless authentication. I have created an user pool and has implemented triggers for phone & OTP authentication in AWS Cognito by following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/m8DE5ZV4FG4

I created an user using the Hosted UI in the App Client Settings in AWS Cognito. But unfortunately I didn't receive any OTP in the number which was used to sign up. Is this the right way to test it? Is there a way to test the triggers without using AWS Amplify, for eg: by using another software like Postman?

Comment: I'm not gonna watch a 15 minute tutorial to find this out, but have you either got your account out of the SES/SNS sandboxes so you can send emails or text messages? Or have you verified the phone number/email address that you're testing with?

Comment: @stijndepestel, Yes my phone number is verified. For sending OTP, I have used SNS service inside the triggers. Do I need to set it up separately?

Comment: If you have Cloudwatch enabled, then for your account ( adjust region/accountId ) you should see a log group where you can tell if there were any issues with the SMS being sent out:

sns/<region>/<accountId>/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber is the log group name.

Answer (score 1):

Just calling those lambdas will not trigger user creation, or confirmation.  User creation happens if a user calls the Cognito signup apis and:

1. the username isn't taken
2. the pre-signup trigger succeeds ( or you don't have one ) they define "succeeds" by saying the event they passed into the lambda was returned to them with only the "response" object modified.

All you could do with postman was expose your lambda trigger(s) through something like API Gateway, and pass in various payloads to see if it responds correctly. that is one way to do it..

Personally what i do to validate triggers is write unit tests that run when the trigger deploys that tests out various payloads to the triggers against an expected response.

I'm not sure what language you're writing the lambda in, but any would have SDK's available to call Cognito directly to sign up a user. That would in turn call your trigger. `await Cognito.signUp({ ... })` for me in node.